# Debugging UnknownHostException: postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

One of my applications is trying to connect to RDS - it's on the same VPC, but I am getting this UnknownHostException for postgres. All of the error messages are cryptic and I don't entirely understand what's going on here. Does this mean that maybe some environmental variable is set incorrectly? Or possibly a security policy?

How do I troubleshoot this most effectively? This is in a docker container on an EC2 instance.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:156)
    ... 57 more
```

My environmental setup looks like this for Kubernetes:

```
env:
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"

        - name: POSTGRES_ADDR
          value: "postgres"

        - name: POSTGRES_PORT
          value: "5432"

        - name: POSTGRES_DATABASE
          value: "name"

        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-user-pass
              key: username

        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-user-pass
              key: password

        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-user-pass
              key: username

        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-user-pass
              key: password
```

Theoretically, I would think, it would forward to my RDS instance.

[image: DB Security settings]

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue? Can you ping the postgres db , see if the ping resolves to the correct internal IP address of the Rds? Telnet IP 5432?

Comment: I'm trying to ping and I am getting: ping name.cgcghsuzur6g.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
PING ec2-3-13-129-183.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (162.20.0.223) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: Nothing other than that

Comment: My security group inbound rule looks like this: 162.20.32.0/19

Comment: 162.20.32.0 is not a private address, so... The Rds is located in a VPC so I think you should try to connect to the private IP address of your postgres db. What is that private address (check that it's in your box range) and try to connect to that address.

Comment: How would I check for the private RDS IP address? I've got the RDS in a subnet group, if that helps. Sorry, I inherited this and it's a bit more complex than expected

Comment: Goto Rds click the instance somewhere there is a private IP listed. In the range: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (65,536 IP addresses)
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses)
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (16,777,216 IP addresses)

Comment: I'm in the instance, I am not seeing any private IPs listed

Comment: I'm seeing an endpoint, VPC security groups, VPC, subnet group, subnets, availability zone, and port

Comment: The domain name of the Rds / database should refer to a private address. That's the whole point of putting it in a VPC.

Comment: I'm brand new to the concept of VPCs (and honestly, to some extent to AWS). Where do I find this? I have summary and connectivity and security on my database instance page. I can also click into the VPC and grab any information from there. Sorry for the dumb questions, I just don't totally understand this architecture

Comment: Post a screenshot of the rds settings, blackout security related settings, I'll check tomorrow if that gives me a clue. Switching off for now.

Comment: Oh I know what's going on. I used a fake IP address, because I didn't want someone to know the application I was working on. It's actually in the range 172.x.x.x